# Advantages of HTML5 in a web application environemnt

Tags: html

I am making a Project management Web application, as it is progressing to the alpha stage I was wondering weather it would be worth it to use HTML5, What are the main advantages of HTML5 and would it be worth learning the additional features?

Thanks,
RayQuang

Comment: This is an extremely vague question since HTML5 refers to a wide collection of development implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the platform / users you want to support for this application. Html5 is not fully supported in most popular browsers so probably it's not your best choice.

If you know exactly the device you users will use, e.g. iPad, iPhone, you can probably try some cool features of Html5, CSS3, but maybe you don't want to totally depend on Html5 if you want to migrate the application to other devices potentially.

Comment: HTML5 is actually fully supported by all browsers (even IE6+) as long as you utilize attributes instead of tags.